# Gdb gives no stack on a simple std::string uncaught exception

Tags: c++, gdb

im a little bit newbie on gdb so here goes:

Im working on cpp unit testing operation right now. I try to construct string objects with invalid parameters like null_char but program expectedly gives exceptions :). When i try to debug the app using gdb, i type bt after the crash, but it gives me no stack message. 
Any ideas to why that might happen? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You debugging the core file, with a release or debug build ?

Comment: I am using a build script that default builds the project in debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `-g` option to your compiler command line to add debugging symbols. That helps a lot with `gdb`.

Comment: and -O0 helps alot too - sometimes optimizations make the codepath seen in the debugging quite "wild" =)

Comment: I go in the code step by step and i think i am in debug mode so there are no optimizations i think..

Comment: Debug flags (-g) and optimization level (-O0 through -O3) are independent.  You can use a high level of optimization even if you have a debug flag set, and it will make debugging confusing.  It's best to check your CXXFLAGS and make sure that the right options are set.

Comment: Thanks dublev, valuable info :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the stack is just not useful because the exception is never caught? Be aware of catchpoints in gdb:

```
catch throw
```

breaks when an exception is thrown.

```
catch catch
```

breaks when an exception is caught.